# Check that the first character of the string is a digit and there are no letters in the string

Tags: php, regex

How to check that the first character of the string is a digit and there are no letters in the string?

```
is_int(intval(substr($string, 0, 1))) && !preg_match('\w*}', $string)
```

This check does not work!

Comment: Do you have any attempt to show?

Answer (score 1):

The regex you're looking for is `^[0-9]\P{L}+$`, and you don't need the `u` flag.

```
<?php
function check($text) {
    if (($result = preg_match('/^[0-9]\P{L}+$/', $text)) !== false) {
        return $result;
    }
    throw new Exception("Error with regex");
}

check('123')    // true
check('1$%#@')  // true
check('12д54')  // false
check('1łs')    // false
check('')       // false
```

Also, with open source [T-Regx](https://github.com/T-Regx/T-Regx) you can do this:

```
<?php
pattern('^[0-9]\P{L}+$')->test('123');  // true
```

Comment: `[^\p{L}]` could be written `\P{L}`